# Delete item from InlineForm in Django

Tags: python, django

I've created an InlineForm to add some Staff Members to a Project, but the form needs to be editable, and when I try to delete 1 of the Staff Members I get an error: get() returned more than one Colaboradores -- it returned 8!
I can't send the ID to the view and can't get the Staff Member to be deleted.
How can I fix it?

edit_form.py

```
def editar_projeto(request, projeto_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        projeto_editar = Projeto.objects.filter(id=projeto_id).first()
        if projeto_editar is None:
            return redirect(reverse('projeto'))
        form = EditForm(instance=projeto_editar)
        form_colab_factory = inlineformset_factory(Projeto, Colaboradores, form=ColabForm, extra=1, max_num=5)
        form_colab = form_colab_factory(instance=projeto_editar)
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'form_colab': form_colab,
        }
        return render(request, 'editar_projeto.html', context)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        projeto_editar = Projeto.objects.filter(id=projeto_id).first()
        if projeto_editar is None:
            return redirect(reverse('projeto'))
        form = EditForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=projeto_editar)
        form_colab_factory = inlineformset_factory(Projeto, Colaboradores, form=ColabForm, extra=1, max_num=5)
        form_colab = form_colab_factory(request.POST, instance=projeto_editar)

        if form.is_valid() and form_colab.is_valid():
            projeto_editado = form.save()
            form_colab.instance = projeto_editado
            form_colab.save()
            return redirect('projeto', projeto_editar.id)
        else:
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'form_colab': form_colab,
            }
            return render(request, 'editar_projeto.html', context)

def deletar_colaborador(request, colaborador):
    colaborador = Colaboradores.objects.get(colaborador_projeto=colaborador)
    colaborador.delete()
    return redirect('editar_projeto')
```

urls.py

```
path('deletar_colaborador/<str:colaborador>', views.deletar_colaborador, name='deletar_colaborador')
```

models.py

```
class ColabForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Colaboradores
    fields = '__all__'

colaborador_projeto = forms.CharField(label="Colaborador do Projeto", widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control col-8',
        'maxlength': '200',
    }
))
```

edit.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" class="form-group" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.nome_projeto.label_tag }}
        {{form.nome_projeto}}
    </div>          


    {{ form_colab.management_form }}
    <label>Colaboradores do Projeto:</label>
    {% for colab in form_colab %}
        {{ colab.non_field_errors }}
        {{ colab.errors }}
         {% for hidden in colab.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="input-group mb-3 inline-form">
            {{colab.colaborador_projeto}}
            <a type="submit" href="{% url 'deletar_colaborador' colab.colaborador_projeto.value %}" class="text-black">Excluir Colaborador</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}


    <br>
    <div class="submit-row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green" name="_save">Salvar</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` if your queryset will **more than one object**. So:

```
colaborador = Colaboradores.objects.filter(colaborador_projeto=colaborador)
```